# Deleting items from RecyclerView throws OutOfBounds exception

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` populated with `CardView`s. In the `onLongClick` method of the `CardView`s, I open a dialog with the option to delete that card, but I'm running into problems with the app crashing. If I have multiple cards and delete them one at a time, it will sometimes throw `IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions` or `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions` when I try to delete more than one in a row.

It's important to note that if I delete one, leave that activity and then return, everything will be fine when I try to delete another. Is this because the adapter is being replaced with a new one?

I'm not sure how to fix the problem. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Also, one other quick quesiton: where in the adapter can I implement a method that uses `getItemCount` to see if there are no cards left, and then inflate a new layout? Currently, I have something like that imeplemented in the `Fragment` class which instantiates and assigns this adapter, but it won't work unless the activity is recreated.

Here is most of the code in my adapter class, which extends `RecyclerView.Adapter<SessionAdapter.ViewHolder>`:

```
private MyAdapter adapter = this;

public MyAdapter (ArrayList<MyObject> mArrayList, ...)
{
    this.mArrayList = mArrayList;
    //...
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)
{
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i)
{
    final MyObject mMyObject = mArrayList.get(i);

    viewHolder.mCardView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
            dialog.setTitle(R.string.title_delete);
            dialog.setMessage(R.string.prompt_delete);
            dialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.delete, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    //delete from SQLite database
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    mArrayList.remove(viewHolder.getPosition());
                    adapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.getPosition());
                }
            });

            return false;
        }
    });

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public CardView mCardView;

    //buttons and things that go inside the CardView

    public ViewHolder(View v)
    {
        super(v);

        mCardView = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_view);

        //buttons and things that go inside the CardView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the prob... where in the adapter can I implement a method that uses getItemCount to see if there are no cards left.
You do this in onCreateViewHolder of recyclerview...

onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int position) {
View v;

```
if(getItemCount==0){
  v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.some_layout, parent,false);
}else{
  v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.some_other_layout, parent,false);
   ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(v);
return holder;
}
```

For the exception prob When item is removed from your recyclerview new position is assigned but the arraylist manages index itself so after called notifyItemRemoved you should call notifyDataSetChanged so it will reassign the position to all the views...

```
dialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.delete, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    //delete from SQLite database
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    mArrayList.remove(viewHolder.getPosition());
recyclerview.removeViewAtIndex(viewHolder.getPosition());
notifyDataSetChanged();
                    adapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.getPosition());
                }
            });
```